# using the invoke to access a textbox on the form

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

i'm writing a simple filestream program in C# using asynchronous reading which uses a thread other than the main thread for its callback.but i'm getting cross-thread exception when i try to write my filecontent in a text box.
here is my program:

```
using System;

namespace Filestream
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        FileStream fs;
        byte[] fileContents;
        AsyncCallback callback;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void synbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            callback = new AsyncCallback(fs_StateChanged);
            fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true);
            fileContents = new Byte[fs.Length];
            fs.BeginRead(fileContents, 0, (int)fs.Length, callback, null);
        }
        public void fs_StateChanged(IAsyncResult ar)
        {

                if (ar.IsCompleted)
                {
                    *textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContents);*
                    fs.Close();
                }
        }

    }
}
```

the part with the star is the part that i'm getting the exception.i tried to use the invoke but i had no luck.can someone correct this part of the code with invoke so i don't get the error.
thanks.

Comment: i got my answer.but can someone point me a good tutorial for using this invoke in threads? or simply explain for me?

Comment: When you change something on your UI like text, color or size the you must do it with the same thread that created the element. The UI control provides a couple of things to help do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
if(textbox1.InvokeRequired)
{
    textbox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContents)));
}
else
{
    textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContents);
}
```

Comment: This would fail if fs_StateChanged happened to be called from the thread that created textbox1

Comment: Unless you need to wait for the textbox to update, use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To Expand on Ram's answer

```
//Can this thread make updates to textbox1?     
if(textbox1.InvokeRequired)
 {
    //No then use the invoke method to update textbox1
   textbox1.Invoke(new MethodInvokernew MethodInvoker(() => textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContents)));
 }else{
    //Yes then update textbox1
     textBox1.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContents);
 }
```

Explanation:
Updates to a UI control must be done on the thread that created the UI control. To test if the current thread is allowed to update a particular UI control call the [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) method on the control. Invoke can then be used to call a method on using the thread that can update the control